# There is no simple group of order $448=2^6\cdot 7$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, simple-groups

How can I prove that there is no simple group of order $448=2^6\cdot 7$? I tried with Sylow's theorems, I proved that (if $G$ is simple) the number of 2-Sylows is 7 and that the number of 7-Sylows is 8 or 64, but I don't know how to continue, could you help me please?

Comment: (There is a monthly maximum for questions... :D )

Comment: Hint: If there are 64 Sylow 7-subgroups, consider how may elements of order 7 there are.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson: $64\cdot 6=384$ elements, right? How can I continue?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: really? How many questions can I ask?

Comment: @Alex: Well, if there are 384 elements of order $7,$ how many Sylow $2$-subgroups can there be? (Actually, I see a more direct approach to the question than this anyway).

Comment: only 1, right thank you

Comment: Is there a way to show the Sylow 7-subgroup is normal that doesn't prove the group is not simple long before?  In general, the Sylow $p$-subgroup in a group of order $q^n p$ cannot normalize a non-identity $q$-subgroup unless it normalizes the entire Sylow $q$-subgroup, but even in the $q=2$, $p=7$ case one immediately gets a non-identity normal 2-subgroup from the assumption of 7 Sylow 2-subgroups.

Comment: @Alex: No, it might be $7.$

Comment: @ehsanmo: if there are more than 1 sylow 7-subgroups, then there must be exactly 1 sylow 2-subgroup.

Comment: @JackSchmidt: right! I'd partially read the comment.

Comment: @JackSchmidt: I'm not sure I understand your claim about groups of order $q^np$. If $P$ is any 2-group, you seem to be saying that the 7-subgroup of the dihedral group cannot normalizes it in $P\times D_7$?

Comment: If we look at a putative (ok, non-existent by Burnside $q^ap^b$) simple group of order $2^n\cdot7$, won't the argument starting from the study of a maximal intersection of two Sylow 2-subgroups always lead to the conclusion that all Sylow 2-subgroups need to intersect trivially. This might actually work for all $q,p$?

Comment: @Jack, Jyrki: I do not believe the statement about groups of order $q^{n}p.$ For example, the symmetric group $S_4$ has order $2{3}.3,$ and a Sylow $3$-subgroup normalizes the normal Klein $4$-group, but not a whole Sylow $2$-subgroup (there is noting special about these primes for this question).

Comment: There is a typo above : it should of course be $2^{3}.3$.

Comment: @Geoff, Jyrki: Thanks for the correction.  In the light of the morning, my proof only shows $G/O_q(G)$ has a normal Sylow $p$-subgroup, which is pretty obvious from *G* being $p$-solvable.  There is a group of order $2^7⋅7$ with no normal Sylow subgroups, and a similar group exists for $q=2$ and every *p* (take a faithful irreducible GF(2) module for *p*, then let *p* act on it and its dual, then another copy of 2 switches them), and its not hard for me to believe something similar works for all *q*. Even simpler: take a faithful $D_{2p}$ module.

Comment: @Jack: Yes, let a group $Q$ of order $q$ act faithfully and irreducibly on an elementary Abelian $p$-group $P.$ Then let $QP$ act irreducibly and faithfully on an elementary Abelian $q$-group $V$. The semidirect product V(PQ) has neither a normal Sylow $p$- nor a normal Sylow $q$-subgroup. This is just what goes on with $S_4,$ which is the case $q=2,p=3$.

Comment: $7\not\equiv 1\pmod{4}$, so if there is more than one Sylow 2-group, then there exist two Sylow 2-groups $P$ and $Q$ such that $P\cap Q$ has order 32, and subsequently must be normal. Similar reasoning shows that for $m>1$, a group of order $2^m\cdot7$ always has nontrivial $O_2$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $n_2$ be the number of $2$-Sylow subgroups of $G.$ Then, $n_2$ is odd and divides $7.$ If $n_2=1$ we're done, but if $n_2=7$, by Sylow theorem, conjugation of these seven $2$-Sylow subgroups defines a homomorphism $G \to S_7.$ The kernel of this homomorphism cannot be trivial so we're done.

Comment: why the kernel cannot be trivial?

Comment: +1: This works for groups of size $2^6\cdot 7$, because that number does not divide $7!$. But curiously it wouldn't work for $2^4\cdot 7$ :-)

Comment: If the kernel is not trivial, it is a non-trivial normal subgroup of G. Then G is not simple. If it is trivial, the homomorphism is injective (a well known proposition). If it is injective, the order of the image of G under the homomorphism has the same order as G. This image is a subgroup, and by Lagrange it divides  $S_7$. So that's why you get that $2^6\,7$ must divide $7!$.